# Problema con relacion DDBB MySQL y Eloquen

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo 3 Modelos (tablas) en el desarrollo de una pagina web:

*Articulo
*Color
*Talla

La tablas deben estar relacionadas ya que "Articulo" puede tener varios colores y varias tallas. El problema esta en que debe existir un campo "Cantidad" que no se donde colocar. Al seleccionar un articulo y seleccionar un color, se deben presentar todas las tallas disponibles para el color seleccionado

Comment: Sé más detallado con tu pregunta, por lo que entiendo solo tendrías que hacer una tabla intermedia entre artículo y talla, y artículo y color, y hacer el count de la relación para saber cuantos tiene cada uno, o agregar campos a articulo como color_cantidad y poner un trigger para aumentar la cantidad cada que se inserte un nuevo articulo con ese color.

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo. Si tienes la idea pero no del todo. Quiero que al seleccionar un articulo, logre tener todos los colores de ese articulo, y al seleccionar uno de esos colores, obtener las tallas disponibles para ese articulo con el color ya seleccionado. Luego al seleccionar una de las tallas disponibles, obtener una cantidad de artículos para el color y talla previamente seleccionador.

Comment: Vas a necesitar una tabla que gestione todas esas relaciones solamente mediante los ids. Supongamos que la tabla se llama `existencia`, tendría las columnas `id_articulo, id_color, id_talla, cantidad`. Una fila con valores como: `1,1,1,300` expresaría que hay `300` articulos cuyo id es `1`, cuyo `id_color` es `1` y cuyo `id_talla` es `1`. Una fila así: `4,2,5,77` indicaría que hay `77` unidades del art. `4`, su color es el... y su talla es..., etc. Luego usarías `JOIN` para obtener la información que necesites sea del artículo, del color, de la talla o de la cantidad.

Comment: Okey, eso suena bien. Y con eloquent como podría acceder a ese campo "cantidad" a través de un articulo?

Comment: @OswaldMorales eso lo obtienes con el modelo numero 1 que te diseñe el otro dia, es lo mismo que dice A.Cedano es un modelo en el cual sabes un totalizado de las 3 tabla relacionadas mediante el indice.

Answer (score -1):

Debes usar la relación Muchos a muchos con Pivote

```
class Articulo extends Model
{
    public function tallas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Talla::class, 'articulo_talla_color')->withPivot('color_id', 'cantidad');
    }

    public function colores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Talla::class, 'articulo_talla_color')->withPivot('talla_id', 'cantidad');
    }
}
```

[Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Por favor revisa [answer] por qué al ser solo enlace qué pasa se este mismo deja de servir? Además considera que tu respuesta debe servirle a futuros usuarios